# Is there a desktop Stack Overflow questions liveticker (widget, application)?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, notifications

I would like to get notified immediately on my desktop when a question of interest (that matches my favourite tags) is posted on Stack Overflow. Does anyone know of a widget or application that does this (Windows).

Or does anyone know if Stack Overflow provides an API/Webservice for this? I think RSS wouldn't be fast enough, right?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/). Now that there is a Stack Overflow API, there are many different user-created applications for desktop gadgets, mobile devices, etc.